# Sqlalchemy / Table object has no attribute _c

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlalchemy, атрибуты

Рассказывать особо нечего...
Весь код ниже и ошибка тоже.
Из-за чего берется ошибка не могу понять...

```
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine, MetaData, Table,
    Column, INT, BOOLEAN, SMALLINT, VARCHAR, CHAR
)

engine = create_engine(
    'postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@localhost/db',
    isolation_level='REPEATABLE READ',
    future=True)

metadata = MetaData()

keys_table = Table('keys_table', metadata,
                   Column('id', INT, primary_key=True),
                   Column('user_id', INT),
                   Column('key', VARCHAR(24)),
                   Column('count', SMALLINT),
                   Column('status', BOOLEAN),
                   Column('value', CHAR)
                   )
```

**ОШИБКА** :

````
# python db_manager.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db_manager.py", line 13, in <module>
    keys_table = Table('keys_table', metadata,
  File "<string>", line 2, in __new__
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\deprecations.py", line 298, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 601, in __new__
    metadata._remove_table(name, schema)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 198, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 596, in __new__
    table._init(name, metadata, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 631, in _init
    PrimaryKeyConstraint(
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\base.py", line 1014, in _set_parent_with_dispatch
    self._set_parent(parent, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 3805, in _set_parent
    table_pks = [c for c in table.c if c.primary_key]
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 488, in c
    return self._c
AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute '_c' ```
````

Comment: Это точно всё? Так как ошибки на первый взгляд нету

Comment: Да,это всё.Может быть ошибка самой библиотеки тогда ?

Comment: Большинство ошибок находится между стулом и компьютером)

Comment: ))000 ну и что я не так сделал ?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была найдена.
Стоял интерпретатор Sqlalchemy на старую версию.